# Calling a variable with a string

Tags: string, r, variables, loops, dataframe

I have many dataframes (`week1`, ..., `week20`) and I want to call them in a loop:

```
for (i in 1:20) {
  function(weeki)
}
```

Intuitively, I want to do something like this:

```
weeki <- paste ("week", i, sep="")
```

where `weeki` refers to the dataframe.

I can make a list :

```
week <- list (week1, week2, ..., week20)
for (i in 1:20) {
  function(week[[i]])
}
```

But it doesn't help because I have to write the names of the dataframe in that list. 
I want "week" to be a list of all "weeki" dataframes and that week[[i]] = weeki

Comment: [7.21 How can I turn a string into a variable?](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f)

Comment: Does `week[[i]] = weeki` refer to the names of the data frames in the list, or to the content of the data frames in the list, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have the dataframes `week1`, `week2`, etc already, try this:

```
 for (i in 1:20) {
   week <- get(paste0("week", i))
   [ do something with week ]
 }
```

Note that you say you want to "call them". You can call a function, not a dataframe, but I assume you mean you want to do something with each of the dataframes.

Comment: Thanks, this get function is what I was looking for.

Comment: If that meets your needs, can you accept the answer?